# What should a servlet return that only is receiving data?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I implemented a servlet that receives a JSON string, converts it into an object and inserts its data into the database. I call that servlet from a HTML page using AJAX and post the JSON string to it. In my case, does it make sense for the servlet to write anything to the response?

Comment: Return the word of success or failure for your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to return anything. Once the request cycle complete, your browser receives the response object of it as a stream. If you want to add something to it.

```
response.getWriter().write(somedata);
```

That `somedata` you'll receive in your AJAX callback.

For detailed example with codes : [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Comment: But is it recommended to just return nothing to the caller?

Comment: You need not return anything if you don't want anything on client side. If you want to acknowldgement return your data. For ex : `1` `0`,`true`,`false` etc even a List of objects in json format.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that you had an ajax call to your servlet, you should probably return a JSON status back to calling .ajax()

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object    to     the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your database operation insert is successful
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

// put a success message into the JSON object .
json.put("status", "success");

out.print(jsonObject);
out.flush();
```

On the client side

```
success: function(data) {
if(data.status == 'success'){
    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
}else if(data.status == 'error'){
    alert("Error on query!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to perform the database transaction inside a try catch block, and return a success / failure status flag to the client, in case the transaction failed for whatever reason.